# else part of the if else statement is not working

Tags: c, if-statement

I was just trying to write some nested `if-else` statements and I don't know why `else` part of the statement is not executing.

```
void main(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    if(a>b){
        if(a>c){
            printf("a is greatest");
        }
    }
    else if(b>a){
        if(b>c){
            printf("b is greatest");
        }
    }
// This else statement.
    else{
        printf("c is greatest");
    }
}
```

**1. but if I write these statements using &&**, `else` part of the statement starts working fine.

```
if(a>b && a>c){
    printf("a is greatest");
}
else if(b>a && b>c){
    printf("b is greatest");
}
else{
    printf("c is greatest");
}
```

**2. If I remove Braces from `else-if` part**, then the program works fine.

```
if(a>b){
    if(a>c){
        printf("a is greatest");
    }
}
else if(b>a)
    if(b>c){
        printf("b is greatest");
    }
else{
    printf("c is greatest");
}
```

**but if I remove every Braces**, then `else` part don't get executed.

```
if(a>b)
    if(a>c)
        printf("a is greatest");
        
    
else if(b>a)
    if(b>c)
        printf("b is greatest");
        
else
    printf("c is greatest");
```

Comment: Which `else` part do you mean? There are several. What makes you think it is not working?

Comment: 1st program's `else` part (The Program inside `main()` function.). Other programs are just the modification of the 1st program.

Comment: The `else` part work as the compiler should do, but your code in the first version is bad: nothing is printed if a>b and a <= c.

Comment: " I don't know why else part of the statement is not executing." --> because `else if(b>a)` is true, so code never gets to `// This else statement.  else{`

Comment: Yes, i didn't thought that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, i didn't saw that coming. I was really frustrated when this program stopped working. Thank you.

Comment: The `else` you indicated in the first version will only be executed if both `a>b` and `b>a` are false, i.e., if `a == b`.  It has nothing at all to do with `c`.

Comment: What happens if a==b ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if`s/`else`s are not exhaustive. For instance, if `a > b` and `c > a` is not covered: inside the `if (a>b)`, you only consider `if (a > c)`, and if this condition is false, you do nothing (meaning, there is no else).

You seem to be under the impression that the final `else` (which prints `"c is greatest"`) should be executed after each `if` that has no `else`. However, this is not how C works: this `else` is only executed if the condition of the `if` that precedes it is false. The fixed version of your first attempt is thus:

```
if(a>b){
    if(a>c){
        printf("a is greatest");
    } else{
        printf("c is greatest");
    }
}
else if(b>a){
    if(b>c){
        printf("b is greatest");
    } else{
        printf("c is greatest");
    }
}
else{
    printf("c is greatest");
}
```

However, the second version (with the `&&`) is clearer in my opinion.

Finally, when you remove the braces after `if(b>a)` (your 3rd version), the final `else` is associated with the `if` that precedes it, which is `if(b>c)` rather than `if(b>a)` (unlike when the braces are present). Your indentation is misleading, and should have been:

```
else if(b>a)
    if(b>c){
        printf("b is greatest");
    }
else {
    printf("c is greatest");
}
```

The same thing holds for your 4th version, which should be read as:

```
if(a>b)
    if(a>c)
        printf("a is greatest");
    else if(b>a)
        if(b>c)
            printf("b is greatest");
        else
            printf("c is greatest");
```

Notice how `if(b>a)` can never be true since it is inside the body of `if(a>b)`.

Additionally, you never consider that some or all numbers could be equal. Without the broader context, we can't know if this can happen, but if it can happen, then you should probably take that case into account.

Comment: Thank You,
I really didn't saw that else if(b>a) statement was true.